# Reputation tabs for week, month, and year?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

## Current UI

Right now the summary tab of a user's activity page shows a section for reputation. It has a graph showing the reputation gained on each of the last last 31 days.

[image]

## Proposed Change

The weekly cycles go up and down by day. I think it would be interesting to see a summary graph of the total reputation per week, month, and year in addition to day. Tabs could replace the current **top XX% this year/etc** label (since that information is already easily visible above). It could look something like this:

[image]

The week tab could show the last 30 or so weeks, the month tab the last 30 months, and the year tab, well, data could be shown for whatever is available.

## Reason

A feature like this would allow people to step back and visually see their reputation's rate of change by avoiding the somewhat random and cyclical fluctuations of the daily graph.

I realize that this is possible to some extent with the [reputation tab graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681880/suragch?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2016-05-06%2000:00:57Z):

[image]

However, that gives more of a fuzzy estimate. A conveniently located summary view would be nice.